# Disable SVC encoding when consuming VP9 in WebRTC

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, webrtc, rtp, sdp

I have a web app which needs to support screen-sharing in (unmodified) Chrome and Firefox browsers through WebRTC. I would like to use VP9 due to its quality/bandwidth advantages.

However, both Chrome and Firefox seem to enforce SVC-encding when choosing VP9 and haven't been able to disable it. This is a showstopper because:

1. The video is consumed by a single endpoint (so SVC encoding only causes overhead).
2. That single endpoint has hardware VP9 decoding support, but the hardware doesn't seem to support SVC. Discarding layers from SVC to make the hw-decoder happy would degrade quality and software decoding is not really an option due to platform limitations.

Is there a way to disable SVC encoding in SDP negotiations or through javascript?